# Passing an argument(filename) to a CLI PHP Script

Tags: php, command-line, text-processing

I am wanting to write a script in PHP to process text files. I know of a few ways to accomplish this, except the one way I would like to do this. I want to be able to pass a file name, like a traditional command-line application.

For example:

`php script.php textfile.txt` or
`script.php textfile.txt`

I assume it can be done, because you pass arguments to composer. I just can't find how to do it in the docs or Google.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Or point me to a language that supports this(maybe Python or Groovy, if PHP is not an option).

Comment: PHP is no problem. You just need at access $argv. Note the file will be $argv[1]. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php if you run it from the command line you can treat any value after the php as an argument. The inside your `script.php` you will have access to these arguments in the `$argv` array.

for the following would be your php script:

```
<?php
// script.php
print_r($argv);
```

Then if you execute that file from the command line:

`> php script.php foo bar testfile.txt`

you will get the following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => script.php
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
    [3] => testfile.txt
)
```

See the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) for more information.

This is a very simple way to create a script, but if you want to create advanced command line tool programs I recommend using the [Symfony2 Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/index.html).

The console component will enable you to encapsulate the functionality of each command inside it's own class. Then you can create a simple "console" file that will be able to execute any of these commands. Take a look at a simple example application [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

Comment: No problem. Take a look at the symfony Console, it is well worth the trouble :) The docs have a very comprehensive example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html